# Reuse properties in Page Object in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am considering automated testing using Selenium and C#

I am using page object pattern and want to reuse element locator properties. Let me explain with an example:

```
public class AdminSection
    {
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "**Admincity**")]
        public IWebElement City{ get; set; }
    }

public class UserSection
    {
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "**usercity**")]
        public IWebElement City{ get; set; }
    }

public class MyPage
    {
//Section could be either admin or User based on the page        
ISection = AdminSection OR UserSection;
    }
```

Here I have a page where I have a "section", I want to reuse properties like name, city, address,etc. However different pages have different element ids.
Is there a way to reuse the properties Name & City with different element locators at runtime? use some abstraction?

I want to avoid the duplication I did above by creating two separate classes? I cannot use FindBy XPath as the XPath address is not the same on both pages, plus it will be brittle.

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: you can define multiple FindsBy attribute with all possible values to each member (city, address).

Comment: I am not sure I understand, you mean something like this?
{
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "**usercity**")]
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "**admincity**")]
        public IWebElement City{ get; set; }
    }

Comment: yes, see https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_PageObjects_FindsByAttribute.htm

Comment: I would not create confusion. Create a page object page for each new application page. Then you want to call each page accordingly. Example page.login, page.passwordReset. So if the login page has email address and so does the passwordReset page, you may have the same identical xpath. if you go the way you want, it will create more work in the end. If one id is changed on one page and not the other, then you start having a mess.

Comment: @RajN Your solution is good however my tests are running extremely slow
.

Comment: @Dazed Xpath is not an option for me as the XPath is different on both the sections/pages

Comment: What do you mean by slow? can u be more specific with some details? Are you saying adding extra attr causing the test to be slow?

Comment: @RajN It takes like 7-8 seconds to find each element with lower priority id. So if I have 5 fields to enter text it takes a minute to run the test for that section alone.

Comment: May need see your executer code to comment on it.

Comment: I tried adding properties with single findelement locator. The ones with single locator are being picked in milliseconds but ones with multiple locators are taking time, I guess the wait depends on the implicit wait time that I have mentioned.

Comment: Not following you 100% here. Are the page object on the same url or different url? It sounded like these were same type of form elements but on different pages. If different pages, create a page object page for each url change. I would also suggest you look at SpecFlow. Great tool for reusing code.

Comment: @Dazed It is a single page(same URL) in a wizard-like UI, it is a mixture of jquery and page loads. I am in fact using Specflow to work on it while developing my test.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you don't do this. Treat each page separately even if they have some/all of the same locators. If pages do have the same locators it's probably a coincidence. At some point, it's likely that one of the pages will change which will force you to update locators for only that page. When you've shared them, you'll then have to split everything or things will get even more complicated.

You'll likely spend way more time trying to figure out a way to share them and write them in a such a way that they work on all pages than you would if you just copy/paste the ones that are the same in separate page objects.

Answer (score 1):

Manoj - Thanks for answering the questions. Based on what you are saying, I might create it this way. It sounds like a SPA where it is a single page application? I would probably still create a different page object class for Admin and User and call each accordingly.

Then you can build out your specflow steps calling the page and method.

example:

```
    adminPage

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "City")]
    private readonly IWebElement _adminCity = null;

    //methods
    public void TypeAdminCity(string value)
    {
        browser.Type(_adminCity, value);
    }

    UserPage

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "userCity")]
    private readonly IWebElement _userCity = null;

    //methods
    public void TypeUserCity(string value)
    {
        browser.Type(_userCity, value);
    }
```

Comment: So you mean I will have to create separate classes, I cannot reuse properties :( Like you created separate pages, I have created separate sections though.

Comment: You can create it any way you like but doing it the way you want I think is going to create more issues down the road.